# Storing user specific data in java servlet?

Tags: java, session, servlets

A majority of my work has all been in .net, but this project was required to be done in java.  So I have a question on handling session data.  In .net, I would just do  HttpContext.Session.Current in my classes and I would have access to the session data.  But it looks like in java, I need to pass around the HttpSession object so I can do a request.getSession()?  Is there a better way to handle this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass it around. Just get the session by [`HttpServletRequest#getSession()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29) and use its [`setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method to store objects in session and [`getAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) to get them from session.

If you think that you need to pass the whole `HttpSession` object around into domain objects, then you're doing things wrong. You should rather get the information of interest out of the session (usually in flavor of a Javabean) and then pass *that* around instead, or maybe just the `HttpServletRequest` instance if the design concerns a front controller.

Comment: Ok, so for my next question, what jar is HttpServletRequest a part of?    I can't seem to get it to resolve...

Comment: It's in the library of the servletcontainer you'd like to use. E.g. Apache Tomcat, Sun Glassfish, JBoss AS, etc..etc.. This is however a story apart .. Starters often make the major mistake to copy a different vendor's one into the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. If you're using a simple notepad and javac, then you just need to add the path to the server library to classpath. If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, then you need to have the Eclipse for Java EE version and integrate the servletcontainer in Eclipse and finally associate it with the dynamic web project. Eclipse will take care automagically

Comment: Ok, today is just one of those days where I can't wrap my head around this...  Does anyone have any good code examples?

Comment: http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html It also covers Eclipse and Tomcat. Don't give up, nobody has learnt Java EE web profile in 1 day. It'll take minimal one month or two of intensive training.

Comment: Can I also store a java object in session from a servlet? I mean lets say in servletA, I create an object of Class1 called Object1. Then I store Object1 in session. Now, I write another servlet called ServletB. Can I access that Object1 in ServletB via getAttribute() of session? And if so, does it happen by pass-by-reference or pass-by-call?